# What exactly happens when an electron absorbs energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, potential-energy, absorption

When an electron absorbs energy, I know that it jumps to a higher energy level. But where does this energy go? Is it used to increase the potential of the electron by keeping the electron further away from the nucleus? Is it that the kinetic energy of the electron in the previous shell is partly converted to potential energy of the electron?If yes, Is the complete loss in kinetic energy of the electron converted into potential energy of the electron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (now known to be innacurate but,) useful way to understand this is to imagine the electron is a small planet (let's call it a planet electron) orbiting a large star (let's name it nucleus). This is of course only a metaphor and doesn't really explain what's happening quantum mechanically but is nonetheless a good way to get intuition and answer all your questions.

At a fixed distance $r$ from the nucleus, planet electron, if it has to maintain it's orbit, will have to be moving at a speed $v$. If the electron is moving at a speed less than $v$, it will then fall in towards the nucleus. And if its speed is greater than $v$ it will fly out away from the nucleus.

Now the "Kinetic Energy" of this electron is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

When a photon (we can imagine it as a meteor in our planet-star system), hits our electron, it suddenly gets a lot more kinetic energy than before. So, it flies out further away from our star nucleus (because it is after all moving with more velocity), but it only goes so far, because eventually the gravity of the nucleus (which outside the metaphor, in real life, would be the electromagnetic force) pulls on our planet electron.

So now the electron is in a larger orbit, at higher velocity around the nucleus.

Where did our photon's energy go? It went into our electron's orbit, and electron now has a larger and faster orbit from the nucleus than it did before. At each point it has more energy(potential energy+kinetic energy) than before.

At some point the planet electron spontaneously emits a meteor (outside of the metaphor, in the real world, this corresponds to the electron emitting a photon).

When it does so, it loses some kinetic energy equal to $\frac{1}{2}m_{meteor}v_{meteor}^2$.

Now that planet electron has less kinetic energy, it obviously moves slower and starts to fall back towards the star named nucleus. But it hasn't lost **all** of it's energy. So, though it gets pretty close, it is moving just fast enough that it escapes and rolls around the nucleus now in a stable orbit.

The metaphor:

Planets can get hit by meteors and move into "higher energy" orbits around stars. And (with some imagination) they can emit meteors and move into lower energy orbits around stars:

The real world:

Electrons can absorb photons and move into higher energy orbitals around nuclei. Electrons can emit photons and then move into lower energy orbitals around nuclei.

### CAVEAT:

In the real world, the orbitals of electrons are "quantized" much like the photons, (being emitted and received,) having quantized energy. Thus, in our metaphor, electron planets can only emit meteors of a certain quantized amount of energy.

In the real world, there are no orbits, electrons instead exist as probability clouds with their location completely undetermined in a classical sense, but their momentum (or velocity if you rescale by mass) is still well defined (so the kinetic energy part of the metaphor still makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

When an electromagnetic wave hits an atom, more specifically, an electron, the electron gets excited to a higher energy level(as you quoted, by absorbing energy).
As you may know, everything in the universe has a tendency to achieve the lowest energy state(I'm not sure if there's a reason why), so the electron wants to come back to a lower energy level, and in doing so, it emits Electromagnetic Radiation(which is the energy between the orbits).